# How to apply existing classes to an id?

Tags: css

I am editing an existing component's CSS. It contains some CSS entries that define form elements. For instance

```
.icagenda_form .input-large {
width: 210px;
}
```

I then created some classes so I can group form elements. For instance

```
#icagenda .icagenda_form .addresses{
border: 1px solid;
border-radius: 2px;
margin: 4px;
background: #f3f3f3;
padding:2px;
width: auto;
clear: both;
}
```

My HTML:

```
<div class="addresses">
Addresses
<br>
<div id="work_alias" class="ic-control-group clearfix">
<div id="work_message"></div>
<div class="ic-control-label">
<label for="work_address_slug">Work *</label>
</div>
<div class="ic-controls">
<input id="work_address_slug" type="text" required="true" placeholder=""    value="" name="custom_fields[work_address]">
</div>
</div>
<div id="home_alias" class="ic-control-group clearfix">
<div id="home_message"></div>
<div class="ic-control-label">
<label for="home_address_slug">Home</label>
</div>
<div class="ic-controls">
<input id="home_address_slug" type="text" placeholder="" value="" name="custom_fields[home_address]">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am trying to make it so that any of these address elements (which are input elements) will inherit the `.input-large class`. I have tried various variations of adding `.input-large` to the above declaration, but with no result. I think there is something basic I am not understanding about CSS syntax and inheritances...

Thanks!
Brian

Comment: provide your HTML code along with the CSS mentioned above. Also create a fiddle of your issue.

Comment: Hi, I took a look at the fiddle entry you made. Thanks! Never knew about that. The issue is that I am trying to set the input fields to have properties defined by .icagenda_form .input-large. I don't want to set the width in the classes for the form sections (addresses, etc). I want them to simply inherit the .input-large class. And I am trying to do that with no edits to html, just CSS. Thanks!

Comment: That's only possible with a CSS preprocessor like LESS for example. But not with "vanilla" CSS.

Comment: where is `.input-large` in your HTML? - @Brian

Comment: Maybe I'll just make the edit in the html and assign the input class to the input elements.

Comment: @Brian You have no `class="input-large"` in the HTML, none of the rules will apply for whatever you added in the CSS.

Comment: I didn't have .input-large in the html because I was trying to figure out how to accomplish everything by just having an addresses class that inherits the form styling. Curious how the pros would go about this! thanks a ton! This site is truly amazing.